# Why I got Permission denied inside Docker container after npx create?

Tags: javascript, docker

This is what I have done in the first place

```
docker run --name=nodesetup -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app 
node bash
```

Mysql2 works fine

```
npm i mysql2
```

when I go for

```
npx create-react-app test-client
sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied
```

I am bind mounted root@83d263a01dc7:/usr/src/app/test-app#.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue with permissions on the host directory that you map. What exactly the issue is, I can't figure out. The container runs as root, so it should have access.

But if you run your container with the UID and GID of your user on the host by adding `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` as an option, it works. Like this

```
docker run --name=nodesetup -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app -u $(id -u):$(id -g) node bash
```

This also has the advantage that the files created on the host are owned by you, making it easier to edit them, etc.